# Can SWT get the location of the blinking cursor in windows

Tags: java, windows, cursor

I'm a beginner in java programming and I want to get location of the blinking cursor in Windows not in Java windows. How to get it? Does Java have any API to do it?

I tried this code, but it gets the current mouse cursor.

```
import org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Point;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display;

public class CursotLocationDemo{
   public static void main(String[] args){
      Display d = new Display();
      while(true){
         Point p = d.getCursorLocation();
         System.out.println("Cursor location is: " + p);
         try{ Thread.sleep(200); } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
      }

   }
}
```

The goal is to get the cursor in another application like Notepad or another text editor.

Comment: What are you really trying to do?

Comment: i want to code in eclipse to get location of blinking cursor in windows not java windows or Frame.

Comment: Example : blinking cursor is in Notepad.

Comment: So you want Notepad's cursor position?  Or do you want the cursor position of a console (command line) window?  Or both?  My original question of "What are you really trying to do" is to get you to elaborate more on your scenario. Because just "getting" the cursor position is meaningless if you don't have a specific goal to do anything with it.  And because reading the cursor position is not a common task, it's quite possible there's a *better way* to accomplish what you want that just getting the cursor pos.  Answer this:If you had an API to get the cursor position, what would you do with it?

Comment: yes i want to get cursor position of other app like notepad or text editor by use java code.

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to call the Windows [`GetCursorPos`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648390%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function as outlined in these threads:

- [Q: Using Java JNI to get cursor information from Windows](http://answers.google.com/answers/threadview/id/275551.html)
- [Demos and Usage of org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.GetCursorPos(POINT lpPoint)](http://www.javadocexamples.com/org/eclipse/swt/internal/win32/OS/GetCursorPos%28POINT%20lpPoint%29.html)

Comment: Using Java JNI to get cursor information from Windows : i try it already but  
it get the current mouse cursor.

Comment: Your question should include information on what you have tried, for example.